# creating accordion with js

Tags: javascript, dom

started learning javascript and I'm now taking my first steps with the DOM.
I'm trying to create an accordion that has some text within each list item. The idea is when mouse is over the list item the

element will show but an error for " *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined at HTMLLIElement.show"*.  even though I can see in the console that the variable has the elements.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var list = document.querySelector("ul");
  var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("li");
  var text = document.querySelectorAll("p");
  console.log(text);

  for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {

    listItems[i].addEventListener("mouseover", show);
  }

  function show() {

    if (text.style.display === "block") {
      text.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      text.style.display = "block";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 298px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: grey;
}

p {
  display: none;
  width: 299px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Home
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      Career
      <p>Suspendisse potenti. Aenean sed ipsum libero. Praesent feugiat faucibus nisl id viverra. </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      Contacts
      <p>Nullam tristique ex eu libero sodales posuere.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: ```text``` is an array of elements so you need to iterate it to get each individual ```p``` tag separately..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan OP should be using `this`

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 Choices :
The First One is Handling with the `<p>` Then you should iterate Over The All paragraph element because the text Variable is an Array !!
The Second One is Handling With `li` Then instead of Using text u Replace it By `this` and The this Keyword in This Case Will Refer to The `li`

Answer (score 0):

First use `this` instead of `text` and the add another condition of display blank as at the first time the property is `""` (empty) OR the reverse condition that checks the element is not `display= none`

and then you have to change the selector to `querySelector` of that perticular instance

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var list = document.querySelector("ul");
  var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("li");
  var text = document.querySelectorAll("p");
  //console.log(text);

  for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {

    listItems[i].addEventListener("mouseover", show);
  }

  function show() {
    if (this.querySelector('p').style.display !== "none") {
      this.querySelector('p').style.display = "block";
    } else {
      this.querySelector('p').style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 298px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: grey;
}

p {
  display: none;
  width: 299px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Home
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      Career
      <p>Suspendisse potenti. Aenean sed ipsum libero. Praesent feugiat faucibus nisl id viverra. </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      Contacts
      <p>Nullam tristique ex eu libero sodales posuere.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```